# Simulating gravity in 2D with Max / Jitter

Tags: max-msp-jitter

A beginner of two months or so with Max. I've managed to generate a randomly bouncing ball thanks to a few L Objects. Pressing the button near the top right of the patch randomizes the x & y velocities. I'm using global values as I plan on adding additional effects/elements to the simulation.

My struggle is attempting to simulate gravity on my ball. The goal is that when the G key is held, gravity will constantly apply to the y velocity of the ball (+ 0.8), and when it reaches the bottom the Y velocity is reduced slightly and inverted. I've highlighted the section of the patch responsible for this action, it is not behaving remotely as expected and I'm truly stumped. Any help is much appreciated!!

Forgive me for the below syntax, embedding max patches are a bit clunky...

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
4494.3oc6ck0biiaD9YO+JT4JOk3kEtORkJUkJOmmxiakxEsDsGsqthN7Lyl
Zyu8fKRBJQYCPBHYUwyNqGBHRK70ciFc2nQy+yWt69mV+8pc2O4OO4mmb2c+
mub2cltzcbmq8c2ur76SWTtyba2up5aqe5Wt+A6Gsu566McuqZwDXcuqNrb8
g8Kp1adDjq2c6+whJyMWeeaJ2O8qyW8xiaqlt2NH3bdA3gITFn.q9CD+vDLS
2CBU.l7ubOn8299erox9T2+T4pWt+A0u4laY9LyWkZr9Sbl2.a9plwktue+K
eQ+iGFG5m9U02eU+vGGE7orBNUgeHuA+Tv6ieM1muZe8+zKUf1KU.N.pvyKV
q9cj.tMERKjBEN4OLgSPEL0ePrvgrgs2KXQ8CVWmOud6xRyXf0L31VtrZe01
GqVU9jcjCF.o4oC62udU+jFXLjFhTVvn..UIMv3xFRChXHMj2c1PejElLYx.
ICnLJsfJbh5RTALI.kkLftrZ2tx1I2My4spbFM74LoYFOCPa03wCP7uOXSE4
VS2qkKNTM40ejDjiJT.mKr.mST7e5PAd532mA3+wI+DrHgnlHzPEiee.qz1V
1uJcJ81icyDs5xFN6lj8o2vT.Y2p4DmHNQIhijZpvPvLNYL6ygYPJwLgWHUX
lNBHSj4V99kx8UI.zP.gztBMzn9FSFnvMgmNTeX4SUaSfgZPH.qEgQTjZJLU
lNK0v72zRsTYWV5nD.rQqUZIBjKCQn+IAGVsob5uNATn9aZnP7BQsrBvPs3r
PWm6g2ZAOLL2KyucxqJfrdaRTJ3QGnLCEfBGnRALnWjeUcQQI82X4NCA0X0b
8nrbGIyMKNYNqSkddtHLb1D4qNheq39BCHZkAfFF+f8dAgxtENHTRrwQoTia
lYejeaCc1MDeYLjeyORM5sB7C1Pdb90mOaa42R.po.Ra7X734jgZlGBHRlJ8
7ZcKQ3EJJOCcwCG57bKu+mT1xfRAam.Z0uIEsXWLFG2QfaIO26PCTq4OZ22Q
frGtFy9Q.vIvbVhjUPbwnlHPEPyLe00xQtsDPI5imidLLnfo.H.pMZWjNWbf
Rv0zGmDNcnCIBwG+zAnPdAhdInPRSL58ikGgMFEhPA+FRgXGZ.MIR.oSg390
u7xhTrruu6M9QyK.u6NmeMPwUUIPxLFjQEMd6Rfpq0R.xQXLHjKyswfIzC.+
srivPMw1d3x+bQt0.lHag6LovKr93gy4+.FtW+H6LjTQ37VAblbw3Bo.X9yS
9CygS9qSPXvj8esZ0D3jpE6pl.RrnAk1l+JP0LjAJav32L9GKohiSbmQnMDk
LsgIKWUjXCajwhJPeuwLA3UJEURFEQ3wqSGYAbkHK4eYyZIH6VhL7EKYhOdY
xkfSJP...hzqEJRir.idyOEAfJnRojyRIYg7wZJxlx2byCibQTTiNEIzbIRn
HZCcOEfT4MTn00ZQar0BORsDYeuRc.+6IlsOZfitg.dm0PG6BCzratXhSU.e
zSIxBN1kKvoIcAfILOwNq8yaVuKwxATHtIiHwCWwGN2QTHY9NHzahraURDFW
ntTJniwABr3xDNkjDNQeamPbw3zAf4WFseu98Ty3GMxYe7Rtct6vqPaYviI4
Xj4e+xKWMa8xIPZJLlSf.MgIEBAEP87ZEMfGPdRbtPHmxMM6BPBbB.IC8vbi
d0hoyR3QanqvOCD3dl1G1S3tjkP+6LFqB0AD2oGa792gu4c6kaMaIwjExGwH
CkFK.bhQBdK8ZvqChn2PV.TKojFjmcy8+0pebXS+vlLzC9Hg.Z2AMv6eTI7x
cz2OSRkY2P3zkoMc1aMkOPM6p5XyzFY1O.vJ4hTHU3Q.vB005cbmkCoBR1kJ
dy7nGDUXyIdYaIDdlzn2+velcWfRYDO8gGlwGkOPrre9O+iSRxofDBPxlySD
Fgi53wc9.9blHi+wC+cX5oC9YOMxSU3tjLYK9oMg4e3G7YTtUnk3He5S.D7F
BPpB7Y1MD5zLo3mfo4fTZSrZZ67CsuyC7jTBtPjg+hxUGW9jjFkidYOBGzHc
.AClR.uXBDXXJEHjf1PHgfnVRwfEJvxaRgBIfmXYBb5RifoqWtrRax4QTh+t
4n1M4Yse3aOaB3Ek0fHal1wcAXvBdP+FBRtgNsnTq.MjXr8KDWd5moxR1Bg+
x78Ea917UyV+s2dAu9TggrvvK2XwHKuh.duP.0OvxdTM1rsZS0pYS1TpbaZ8
qkKRwQmxBZLxvOg.VLr0mWuZ+t4+l4Cf5TG5zCRSyTX88tRMKy7Q+ssy6L5y
B4ZQ4rYJc7.y+a9a5nWHAZ.zKeByY73udrT9Z0rGU2n5K9wx862N+oC6s0As
6ZnBFxvh46Z3AHJy7AF5Wpnh69V4FsUkvB6OSHQzJzIG7ozhdiPC2cdmRhZo
EphfUeRu7s0nGuR7ISjKxLsTEtAmvAztKTTwPENvezDNNag7gozMkji8saIZ
W9IMzj5FAeSJ2Su777EKltdw5sOV+q59W1VNatmAV92j4mP62HnPJY.tRlUc
ERRz64lkc6MLO4gQ0Or4tq+wa9HQ8DJa.sDWDGzrJl+MrY65Mq2te95Ul4rE
z99kbX+5Fxf4tRny8KzRgIeJFbbmMdn7FQ+axxCHGgyNAiL3SMQ12xCskwKl
NaBYxzuVtUaYq1r1TT5brlMisJmgv.7BPMVdbYoh6+8yePiyd7v28FR.QsDL
jagrk.zS9e0IQOyMr1O4I0+McQU41DTtXfHq0rViZYvv2Tq5+0NR5kVj8367
uWVse6ZcAKDmhPbYoEPa1wvwiIsPRVLuSV5O3jhsAyc70x1qTZOjrCRriY6h
s8HN9vzKxYGbS4ppEIPWFQA3583Gy4ME1VrwJnID0xblOkz6D52DpKWOqxe7
bFKr5XplDQIRskZXFgCXlqHPH2bER1LHN1XLrziFZtq6WLe0wEMbC9082kvt
a8gsSqYq04ivjVV+rpc6mupr9a6ma2udua5qymMqZkOdWNe1l0Jojc0NtQaK
QGLaRzaifvQs.hlCfUcdFn6pc3LemVxY14EcRJNMU.jwBT.2GntVtpnNvKKS
zckCfxBAn5y8eL.sCKBeJWCmItFICRmmHtcgj.wgfkHE.4DpdCpkFU4Bb61T
o64pAB3f.gMIR7ZjiwOJjYG5XaGC.7I7Pa4HU.MUWYSqbfCXP3fLHFgCBbBK
mPPm9voe9.WbQmODFHfi.Ddyvyw3ODwnHG9ZAFsbC0tGKdsx..3grbGUDICP
Xj7oB67.k2Cn5l4.Bz.f.OxE43LlcPaC2UMhnYBBgnV0Tk4Fp0U7Z6orKRzs
ksNmRs6KP2VLl6zqBZVf2zUNHBAPCzBhvHlJIDVUv1seSHaZkgwOSlElHPV.
cEqRt6.05XTcZcAYTrPz5w3wgSIkzjXLXIvtSeG0UNvRPl6iizBYVq4vLn0B
YKjNpkMWW3PZApo76lIbFhm.rXmdAvhlJBN1J.JksI3DNWBf3PAyPE.sYs2I
ckArPCYxDMVCQcK4x3tUfsEpEddV8hFxBvzXW.1Nl41Hm62JGHHjYGT5vP.j
3i.HIOHHjoDD9.MBxtyebapWzsEwtoFPfElG0DYKillziumlP6wDCnlm07Zx
BlGcFzf7bMx4YRdacSzdVPOtmbfj.sSZ.tb.P9tb.xicRDYFEUItsZrVbray
ONhijPr1kDYTF6NxItbzixMmACRdbfjDRjTLVeDkgEJNRyJu.GPHdGwFPlPC
HKnwxBtj.AGxjLicTQ.DIrMfPHlYFkjQ61UNvhHKXg0VKGrKkIrwqnaqKINC
wWDTj3jBsN8xD1sUQzzJGH.1Yv0OBvQpZGplvz9t5xlO4PHD09NYhPyGZdO9
QrwHVAFt2adLm0RJqlntl4.HgnUCCGAPnR25rG2WFPCRFzNzE6tZo2N+Ze1s
t+wH.yaGASYQOSt+gBJBxQNigXO1kXmzElzzJGHHDKYXiXOFYtDLxt+VcaQE
VNkW.WLccsvIBMdbpCQjeW4.KAsRiXXRcVX32JGHHDufPrAg.jMWn8akCDDh
G6H5fPfyDF+VWMDPFFOvl3GTrnIiOLckCXDzluHibhs+rXrzKB8G0xEPX+Ue
fYRAVP64cj3zYdozeNel1qUyKXr.1fEdrFHSZ1fE8KBESDtNpqrflfV2LR1A
Q1taQtf+5uAR4JBvGuqVmi0Do1rNalkDbx9aIyEqIncTFMbvvQtybi2FzhxS
flfAkxNTbr6JYal3Qso0esEYcZQjtTgouVBabjqibm.jIBPndUOf0YwcVmMS
Y5CLnrjw7BIKpkn7bugayp6S5JKngGj+axQfFazdOoqrflvxWT9vQCy9p38j
txBZBIRAb5HRXTti0XMwtSK8qjzV0CG0xFa91cjBeEI.DYdH.uo1RBri1Rx0
TB3XiWFBEfZOqtca4LNtiYLX4UDolWmUikWebWWOzvR.eS3K45ZUmDRd2toq
rfzL3FiaEbaI61qwUa7yPCB.BqWy1yqUmFtPZBZes1Stp3ClX747pl6k8QYR
uAOHqw3hXyYLQaUgjxNNplltxBZDAqEDNrLfiHX9p1Opk0tSDv61yjcm7fr6
jOhHU+VdB4LfwOPOYyHlvP5XVKvkCPmzUVPSPYtSzo6Gi6ki5Rk4TYLE0CDC
T9Xvff0lyD4CHgrShzXy9H6FTIY9aWUlhhHjElBuHWexI.4Bfneqrfgf1Kpw
L+1dD1Ooqr.lvlaDsOWsV5vOw1mbYaGCFLVhY0TOqZrF8nW9zumbfEpLTCsg
Cis.c4nmv8JEoSK6gaPeLfotVYAigYSPjQVyWSrSivIckEzPBH8ahekRTalR
4xyi5kKyTFd.CJerid4xNKPZUvcRWYAM3fPCYDnw598IckCzDhLFgG8AIg1p
Vf5z..c0D0NMQ.WJSovZSptBHWQrFcdS0GV8x2UXtb0KjIUX4vy.dGXDRhGe
y0xse9cxfT.+JhSwnwYmLHMW7rfx8UXroToPmhA0um5rQdUHvE752oaTwUEM
rwili6JKngGZxhGCX73CXaxgz8X1Aulnw7Jrdvvw9Vg5jtxBZXgly3CTPywa
5bDAyFqIn8XLZIMezfw0UciNckEzDR1U.iMy2pKXH1.J52JKXHHCTQQW+PXd
XvuUVvPHKSFI.7OIy3SOby4xwGXFRhZ2ofCy5DUJFKeH.kZDvsm7K6RhNDjs
UCgA46YjHfx7QfsZNDFBrU1sxMadsZ6N2nvL3ueY4uXqhb7GLMmux1zLFtea
0qyqueaOkam9046qlt+vVaMx66tWKSlxV21UGl6JMkJx1Wb0RuiplbsUx9Cy
lu9etub+gcO9OpVcvVU7TTqmKOrXeWRrW0B93hfaSgT19oO35taoLV4jNzT4
jUKNwQ1Bjm5B8dp2vmbOSS4VlPIRfo9GSXHNgZtRfvTrovKezi0Vnkk.nz9M
.jB.wdkpKXmpnb+E1u9JQeM2+wUI4NE62GbRnaUe5wkvv6WpHnyqeFeI5Flg
ip+n8QsOk6MkbGFQ2xNntdTa.nPSff5qThoBF93BFcmGiIP.rgvxTDHp4JNQ
vgL2i4iHWkp77CBvCd+3s9VwL02g4akHX1uUl.C0ENQ+GqZQk98cRmmkKXLt
Q.P.Ty7rWQn.DpmQrqHq1YDqK0p1Zc87U5IgUwM5gtOs8GM2W4zoGOZYTkfm
Ad5+XgrSB9jA66Iv.CRfotjV9oHymhLmWGyxxc5J3puJlpeaV4z+aJXUuC.d
CNknQ6tfCnBg8JAAC6A7FTtawb0hcidT2GKx+65kx4qNOsAZ+BDLHgXFyPlD
Aee3FCq94CqlVuTTlYP9esuK8kvfPfcAYIhQLq1RkPg9sivPlQLV5T0uUN6l
RL9czS6jsjTfUCMXbJmSkZxe8cDLxHGNcqoLBhULC3apkTpe+tL5Q666kvQu
tUN1n+2Udrei9Cad6IdkbE8TP+VEw5sVxjOhb17gkZm9h1MuOYfizxceyvZL
b+SCw9zPrOMD6SCw9zPrOMD6SCwx153EeZJ1+GZJFvsKLe42+x+CZrLix
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

The problem with typing the G key to have gravity is that if gravity is turned off, the ball will always fly away.

[image]

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
3325.3oc6bk0aaijD9Y6eEbEVLOriiReerXl.rXedeZebv.CZIJGlHQpkjxw
Yt9su8E0koHaR1hNAvBIxTRjr6uppt5up5p4ue6MydH+4jxYQ+yneI5la98a
u4FyWo+habe9lYahedw53RyoMa057rcalcm8mTGluqZcRk4GQtuMco4Tye3S
uCwk0m613h3MIUIE2mjE+v5D84.b+l8lT80sI19xrY2EM6g3rGmE8q6u7pEe
LM6w6KRVTYOKJhMGbWDjw0+gBzuiPyA6uFU2KMqt2Ace4p7hMwl6.S+E+4s2
pe6NOweVxWT3pFSUIOatSyph.yaVn.aRnHlcIfqju5NWanlQLnFaPMh1ApCG
FKSVGAA3dn6oWDlFcqRG2JRYP9bHhpvJkMWhwXnPZeIv2EQ3sibT3P9mS95t
sMiaRS3lbQbmlUog8K+iexALvYoSaC4fvg7U8vnFOFiZ2PYmQsrc.NDU6h7M
aRzx6yP3WaFgflPHbVKHPR0cZJEMGKvXB0YpxTnRZ.EHjiQuDbdtGvAzBbHX
p0lap.zEL.+GQuC1COqL4HLB4D1blAyLkoGE.fBf8ER4uACCu+lKoEeHeW1h
jnhjk6VjrWKUjTpN43pz7r6WmlkrPcVUG6DpacNC2hNWvMyrPj7WnwEhISiq
TSK2jTVplQU1CE+k841pNWnUnJLyjuDyfvO0ZeoOwnWO5S0PuA08zvk5RV+Y
IOkTD8XdTUddz57u3uKMVqdnIFyajcfrjGdKZsYa7iIu.PPFXdjDLGxDXIze
iZJeXF0XJ1LaJ.LWwZBqHg6do7sIkSFsoswK9rZTbunFSwCCxD.1RG1.OFbx
.o5tltY2FkY0kfYSiqonNlmxCZgDp3H6YAYxf7trtzrMAYhraH28bz05YfwC
EmLYQ+TEsJZUOPqHDncOy+lXg0EKYX3IjDmsL5wh3mRq5AsYRaNkYbnEgJzM
mqBkWy6x7hvUdvffoi5rEi9iKLqMbQTDJ3JbwHXilC.c3hSTy4JlPBz8g+Ld
LYlXu0ZiX9ZDT2Evb5pn+9JXzGh.Q+vOnNDE8geV6fNp5iIYpOiiRVWlbjf4
D1zH+kVxgMYECwcAZHjuLPCH1XcnB.6BRJ7qnQORzVPipvDlVi9KAq3saW+0
96pBwa0UE1p0z9rdgqJNaxFR+ip4cwG5pcamhnAYTcSvlLczIqhdnOy.iPcl
8QuyKEC6SZoBnJ988xqMBFfTuAHWqTuEFFUPPP3ORYSKiptxxAF3udFLvjb.
AlUIfflq3MCfH23W.T41hOYLn+auWGQZOBFDJPivt1AZH.Zyxwj4m5o306Rh
1lW5OPYfgoXoB2TRDbC9lYfIS2NnPBgsjeigLjlPsroT7NbBAzjFhnUwWtMI
Yo+pdpXfI7XOpaR0ywSYfw9iV7XxO+dHyA1r0pF2XegOrnDSCjeH5A+My8fI
RmIqcO1wxFT2Xz23izAAI4OGb28JORuJZceL..sjGWeT9HgaU9gSLMzALUFf
NtD3JM+YBm5pu5RTPzkPj3ZoKuzpPn56yiHyUrpDRh2JTw.4bRwDmyZAoAm0
cU2Jgb0TcoAHJMKZa5yIqKeeIx6bBbfCZqwF6VvE92l40iGjocesSq2.VOIN
ejrq3DpclFTcoGQmzkWZebhx4BuQMaf9fckVF1L17afk+lgthEOnEq1Atup0
N3PBafxFqccSdkmvnFbon+m94C4n+mhfzn+3Orot+nu+CQXnK08uC1Zl6w9J
9HCU7wXsl3dVcpFljjg5OqEb.h.QX85IL1HSX.G8mCJZfTV3bybYbz0hAZK0
GhhQTORDHbT.jXqhzNTg0lQJ1SKSSrCvp6KO73h704E16JXtTx.bwc5iPRBD
oORSG5nas6JP0Wh4bpe6zSbU550lS99ZbcnOzvIYdG1qtxYWb+5Tmfbuth3c
U4GKE08nFNqrGsyqg3MeBaKx2lWnq9O6Mg9pxrBNv09z4FARULm0zo1mLZ1j
xqZX4pabPVZ9yDNIaeqXe4HqWeEmB12H0qu2UqeKKqzvJV+8BAUD9FxU0Lr.
hIsz8GxxPfFlAdcNMZpdCuFyi9vtpJkWPewkDOnvH7kQjZ5zWrrZHatHISvf
7h3rk4aTi4722sD0pMeaXVphGVnGZWGOL2kMmW5Le5VwsgHBfCVDT6N+UFz5
LCXcK6al75v8dqX1VtzMYp6pB0IoLD+2eT0QShVoGEWDW4ecKQZIIdPqKJKs
e2pFOIovaHbPvrwUR3rqFGjOkVMe6WRUiD+h+wkdYFUpa28ahqJRetSdGTCl
nP1bAS8RVabhzwoZm9gLE5ysEIaSxVFsMV4BIWoc8Oft841aUdVUY5uYjBPz
bP2Ja8UjoFOXtY+qhzCMaSiiMJdhhKlVRQ.Nm3P7gB.ZRp9k3kKiTTuL+27u
drSeFHIbKxgMhblegBWF+Txx6U8B0c893JkwohIhc+SeydAfQBrNsbuZDQMI
KzJ5Bk.r7Kwa0QrAmaeuG6vhwH+v1XXj3u2DXOk771BSpE+QcRE6QEQONJwR
i+GgX53BEsrH9K8nFqFE9rSZR5HURALpF8rLqWrLhDs3iwEZ+6Zm69u7s7vM
gCwohmvBOorEkKno.5ZYp.qpys6gHjos3YhVrNItnYffa.HP+xes5u1ab2ZO
2NHpqTNEPf++TQdVjGgwyw9yYe3T1svz8HCnKBenq+h4wudqkmizNGNcqkWU
9i5z05850MHv2UjnVUrE1WiLNrMNKYs+daZamgfb6LDLWZWhY4bSgboXhpSm
.mTWHWx10ZaxWdhL6BYM+zkm.QIRcN5wLBWGkt5HBDxMGgNzfmmfcr7HYl4r
LK23YOubLnU+8mJHKy2UrnVQt+QgSzAsyxjxpzr35l6WNZuZDAi90FUW92VX
eZq5dzHaKwD1VTuZKQHZK8pr4QagCPaImrVRGoUmM0ocmMoK2lqbE4r6YRR8
SkGkiGcrT0Y6U.uq0eczJehWhIZPDSb6vvVaKSk8Fn1pSbcpkedwxjhK6WOv
sMQ1biCFmB0GmT66giqoXdY6vBgsit3R5roLtCgi1xwGGGl9ynG7Ybb.8ooF
utxKm7rfLgByKWu5ssPDZrsk9YBPmhPaaMZbg8CWhfYE5GtFsYHwq1hFB+x6
uKczV3PHCY90VmNqTn7CS8yQbHbNd9TIsITG8DqTelD2NrDDjA29Mfa7LS8w
AImGB6RpW7CpYUFfoX7Zhyw6dT3crXiss7JrOXP7560Dmrf3azv7sygVlPnf
Aos.d0ViVBNcMkWCrNC5AxgOzKIpYqoNdmvdYoX1Azi2pD3CK+PDOgOCzDsF
EsoPvjLWoF6Ndj8JebpAgc2sfT7g9k4Ci0HPf7TfAmfQUm2aBUrzLfWznjAg
ZiW5ZZHr0gdEKAODME2G0GkccxDhO9ovgH.WLyKphmzcNabJlgLiMsO0+vL7
9OMVksWrUBSJ1P9JF.SRzUm2gBkgkWiTCCqLuxXMYpFnp25vgOZUnOMMNDVn
BeFKfCghC6iuGYvZoNy+eH32JwSkzS50n6Pj9IIz2VZ7IexqbfFjTf5SKEjP
AfdEIPHvjW9b4swDVZlfkXenhXYBa9PHjAiqmY6LXaUKezGBQOCMpdlZFTy1
aQbTWy7gS5Z1UROd61mRJJc2dSuZ1l3OYW0dwclOllY+nYw+mUj7TZ84apuj
YwEK9XZUxhpcE1xe8Y2iAdSYBTjsK0M8sRdnZxxput97Uu+PkytaYZ9+sJtZ
W48+mjrc1hYPIFVEuac0oxti1UdmWJi62xh1e8N2We5lFTRfPydTDCwbjsfD
TGPoGM7vcM62XiDJQBL6zPBCwITyQBDlhMawwytrCaoQI.Jss.PJ.D6QpuBd
x9Ur4BonoRhX+4e9lZ7jR17NmoWg5WMhciLwIS2nDno0Wywlp6UFNo981K0d
Utpp5DEgt1praNxzLs0TRMrA2czaMrOTc1qte8va6Ou3EKTc8STaLpRBpuk5
BHlwsGYUEvCl31NqaGJclUyo2NABfMJTlRwPMGwIBNjcZO4zRYQu6VMJQgtk
g5ifTlfganS3pQoV6DXlpIMcBhfY6DLAFpqWlK1ItnvMYcxlykZbgRVYrVE.
nPXOhPAHTC83tLXfdYvTWIRuYx7lIyk8wrItTWFde25ho9gIvn6scOW1Ya+9
ymZpS8UySM0EXuvbmuhymo2ACVNEAy9nmV6I+V7xE+U6iO8RrNhgmh87ODb.
UHrGIHX3j4UCZ6rRJv5OKzNU7wM3P7E2K4bebFrZW1hZq5qrkwoliKi+txbr
bcpKITWnC2h+5SZUBCBAVR3RDiX7HQkPg9YORHUrl4wBVutcs4mapc7qUFKL
eLNM6uZug0ZZHgXtiPlDACaOX2FcPe8NLu2lZbjL2OlF12mD2eiH100Za9aT
wdiJ1aTwdiJ1aTwdiJ1aSNFnrtaWEFyd8TyEqbarc0fLaIza+ya++pIMoOB
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: Absolute legend, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Obviously I was pretty far off the mark, thank you!

Comment: As for gravity, when G key is released, I will revert back to a different function that allows the ball to bounce without gravity in a frictionless environment.

Comment: Right, so it would bounce against the upper boundary then, I assume. In my example the ball can go over the upper boundary, but it will come back due to gravity.